# User login through Forminator form but her data not shown in all users table. in

Tags: wordpress

I am using Forminator form for user registration, where a user fill her information and submit the form. Then a mail sent to her email address for account activation, once she click that link her data will be shown in all users table under users menu.

But there is a user who fill the form I can check her data in Forminator -> submission where it show pending approval in front of her account and after 5 days somehow that user gets approved in Forminator but her data not show. In users->all users . Then with the same name that user fill form with different details but same username get approved after 5 days but not shown in users. It has been a month and it's still going on.

Can anyone tell me the reason what's going on and how i can prevent it to repeat

I tried to login with forminator form and search for ways to do same. but I did not get any. I tried to login with wp-admin also but issue is not their either. Now I don't know where to check.